# Does not work properly id generation on ui:repeat My faces 2.2.9 + prime faces 5.3

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, myfaces

Actually I'm working with `Myfaces` version `2.2.9` and I've the following structure to generate any panel according with a specific number selected by the user.

```xhtml
...
<ui:repeat value="#{garajes}" var="garaje" varStatus="loop">
<p:panelGrid >
    <h:outputLabel value="Numero de garaje #{loop.index+1}: " />
    <h:outputLabel value="Matricula  #{loop.index+1}: " />

    <p:inputText   value="#{garaje.numeroGaraje}"   maxlength="5" >
    </p:inputText>

    <p:inputText id="matriculaInmobiliariaGaraje-#{loop.index+1}"   value="#{garaje.matriculaInmobiliaria}" 
        maxlength="20">
    </p:inputText>

    ...

</p:panelGrid>
</ui:repeat>
....
```

So, when is rendered  the above code the identifiers are weird, has another things like the following image:

[image]

So I don't know how to remove this weird things inside of id

**Note:** I need a specific id to update another component inside of the loop.

What can I do to get a right identifiers inside of `ui:repeat`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As to the concrete problem, just give all `NamingContainer` components a fixed ID. This includes the `<ui:repeat>` itself.

```
<ui:repeat id="garajes" ...>
```

As to the concrete requirement, you're overcomplicating things. A `NamingContainer` will all by itself worry about uniqueness of IDs of children. Your attempt in `id="matriculaInmobiliariaGaraje-#{loop.index+1}"` won't work at all as `#{loop}` variable isn't available during view build time, when the component is being instantiated with `id`. Get rid of it. You can inside a `NamingContainer` just use a relative ID to reference another component in the same `NamingContainer`.

```
<ui:repeat ...>
    <p:inputText id="foo" />
    <p:inputText ...><p:ajax ... update="foo" /></p:inputText>
</ui:repeat>
```

This will work just fine.

#### See also:

- [How to find out client ID of component for ajax update/render? Cannot find component with expression "foo" referenced from "bar"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156/how-to-find-out-client-id-of-component-for-ajax-update-render-cannot-find-compo)
- [How to use EL with <ui:repeat var> in id attribute of a JSF component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18358604/how-to-use-el-with-uirepeat-var-in-id-attribute-of-a-jsf-component/)