# index of ui:repeat is empty

Tags: jsf, indexing, repeat, is-empty

I have no clue why the index of this example is always empty:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{data.weekdays}" varStatus="day" step="1">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="#{day.index}" value="#{data.weekdays[day.index].value}">
                        </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
...
```

What's wrong with that code?

Comment: But it displays the index when I write <tr>#{day.index} ... So why can't I use it in selectBooleanCheckbox as id? The documentation says something about the scope -> This scoped variable has nested visibility. 

But what does that mean exactly?

Comment: See accepted answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15114086/ui-repeat-varstatus-not-working-in-compositecomponent. The important part, EL-expressions in id attribute must be available at build time.